# Which is the best way to avoid SocketTimeoutException?

Tags: java, sockets, url, jsoup

I'm coding little app which scans all pages by `URL` using `Depth-first search`. So I should connect a lot. After `n` page I'm usually catching `SocketTimeoutException` and my app crashing. So which is the best way to avoid this? Maybe increase `time out` or something?
This is how I did using recursion:

```
public static ArrayList<String> getResponse(String url) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements links = doc.select("a");
            int j = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
                if (links.get(i).attr("abs:href").contains("http")) {
                    resultList.add(j, links.get(i).attr("abs:href"));
                    j++;
                }
            }
            return resultList;
        } catch (HttpStatusException e) {

            resultList.add(0, "");
            return resultList;
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            getResponse(url);
        }
        return resultList;
    }
```

It should send requests until no `SocketTimeoutException`. Am I right?

Comment: A timeout exception is not a bad thing at all. If it "crashes" yor program, your program needs improvement. Without knowing the specifics of how you use your sockets there's hardly any advice to be given here.

Comment: Please, look how I updated post.

Comment: Your recursion will not quite work this way. You may want to check Jsoup's docs for how to configure socket timeouts. However, there are cases where a timeout will occur no matter how long you wait, so you should be able to handle this case gracefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the routine a bit:

```
public static ArrayList<String> getResponse(String url) throws IOException {
    return getResponse(ulr, 3);
} 

private static ArrayList<String> getResponse(String url, int retryCount) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (retryCount <= 0){
        //fail gracefully
        resultList.add(0, "");
        return resultList;
    }
    retryCount--;
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(10000).get();
        Elements links = doc.select("a");
        int j = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
            if (links.get(i).attr("abs:href").contains("http")) {
                resultList.add(j, links.get(i).attr("abs:href"));
                j++;
            }
        }
        return resultList;
    } catch (HttpStatusException e) {

        resultList.add(0, "");
        return resultList;
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {

        getResponse(url, retryCount);
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

This sets a timeout for each connect to 10 seconds. A timeout(0) would wait forever. this is however dangerous, since you might actually never finish your routine. This depends on how certain you are that you can actually reach the URL.

A second mechanism is in place to avoid indefinite recursion, which is probably why your program failed. Handing over a counter and only retry if the counter is greater then 0 does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things seem odd--without digging too deeply.  (a) What're you using "j" for?  (b) it looks like you're opening a new socket for each request (Jsoup.connect(url)), but it doesn't look like you ever close your sockets.  Given the recursion, you could well have an extremely large number of sockets open at once, and the earliest ones are certainly going to time out and close themselves eventually.  So I suggest as a first pass that:

1. you close every socket you use, once you're done with it, and
2. consider limiting the depth of your search in some way, so you don't end up with thousands of open sockets.  Most systems can't efficiently handle more than a few hundred open sockets at once.

I think you need to call "execute()" on your connection object to actually perform the "get()"; not sure if that's related to your problem or not.

Comment: digging deeper: why are you adding the "0" element at the end of resultList?  I don't see any obvious way to close your sockets using the tool you are using (Jsoup), but I'm not familiar with the library.  Finally: as Hanno said, by itself, a timeout exception isn't a big deal--but you need to understand why it's happening, and handle cases where it's unexpected.  Try catching the exception and writing out what URL you were calling when it happened.

Comment: a)resultList's size and links size is not the same. So I should use another iterator. b) I don't really know this, because it depends on Jsoup low level.